# How do i move files from a docker image into a folder on the computer

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I'm building a docker image which I need to copy a file added to the image into a write-protected location on a Linux machine (/opt).

so far I have tried doing this by adding the file to the docker image and then using a cp command to move it into /opt as shown below:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ADD test.txt / 
CMD ["cp", "./test.txt", '/opt']
```

this doesn't work at all even when trying to move the file just into the desktop so I would appreciate at explanation about how to do it properly.

Comment: Is `/opt` in the container?  Building a Docker image shouldn't be able to change anything on the host system.

Comment: Use [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) against a running container

Comment: It's not clear what you are actually trying to achieve, here. In this Dockerfile, you add a file and then copy it to another location *within the image*. Can't see what you mean about copying it to a Linux host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to share a volume between the container and the host.

If that is the case probably your best approach is to create a docker compose file, similar to the one below.

```
---
version: "3.3"
services:
  fileserver:
    image: "your-docker-image"
    volumes:
      - /opt
```

You can find more information in [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)